# How to write a POST request with SSL version = TLS, I got SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0

Tags: ruby, ssl, curl

I want to rewrite this curl script in Ruby

Which use POST to put some data to server via SSL

```
  curl -k https://<SERVER_ADDR>:443/ -i \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -X POST -d @${1} https://<SERVER_ADDR>:443/service/
```

This Curl script works, but the following ruby script not works.

I use the rest-client library https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client

I got the error`#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>`

```
header = {
  "Accept" => " application/json",
  "Content-Type" => "application/json"
}

  resp = RestClient.post(server_url, content, header)
```

How could I rewrit the curl in Ruby version ?

Answer (score 1):

RestClient defaults to SSLv3, which you should not use for security reasons.  To change to something slightly more modern:

```
RestClient::Resource.new('https://<SERVER_ADDRESS>:443/service', :ssl_version => 'TLSv1').post(:json_key => "json_value")
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont see this documented anywhere on github read.me..https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client  you sure its valid?